# Travis CI cant find our gradlew file

Tags: android, travis-ci, gradlew

We are trying to integrate our android app with travis CI. But it always fails with `cannot access ‘gradlew’: No such file or directory`. We can run the gradlew script from our local computer and the file is tracked by git. What can the problem be?

Our `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: false
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8

before_cache:
  - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
  - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
  - $HOME/.android/build-cache


before_script: 
  - cd TreasurePleasure
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t "android-"$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL --abi $ANDROID_ABI --tag $ANDROID_TAG
  - emulator -avd test -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - tools # Running this twice get's the latest build tools (https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Setting-up-Travis-CI)
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-27.0.3
    - android-27
    - android-$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-$ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL
  licenses:
    - '.+'

env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=27
    - ANDROID_EMULATOR_LEVEL=21
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_TAG=google_apis
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20

before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"


script:
  - "./gradlew clean build connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --stacktrace"
  # run tests  against the emulator
  - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
  # run tests  against the JVM
  - ./gradlew test
```

Most of this is copy paste since this is the first project for us that are using Travis CI.

Our error:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that at the location the chmod command is executed no gradlew file exists. Can you log the paths and see whats in there?

Comment: @Vall0n Yes I know. Do you want me to log the paths in the script? How can I do that? You can see in my `before_script:` I do a `  - cd TreasurePleasure` That is because that that is the folder that has the gradlew file in the git repo.

Comment: But it looks like the file is missing on the remote machine. Is everything pushed from the local machine? Maybe the repo is not up to date. Have a look at the path on the remote machine and make sure the gradlew file is there.

Comment: @Vall0n Yes the `gradlew` script is located in the repositroy the path is `TreasurePleasure/gradlew` (I am looking directly in github)

Comment: Maybe you can use the absolute path to the gradlew file

Comment: @Vall0n Ok! Do you know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Just for testing if it works, try sth. like this `- chmod +x /absolute/path/to/TreasurePleasure/gradlew` under before_install in the travis.yml

Comment: Is it possible to have the link of your github repo? I will fork it and try to debug if you wish!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in my scripts:

```
before_script:
- cd ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/TreasurePleasure
- chmod +x ./gradlew

script: "./gradlew assemble"
```